# Firebase notification not working on iOS 11.1

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, ios11, swift2

I am using swift 2.3 and Xcode 8

I tried to upgrade to Firebase v4 then came to know, v4 supports only swift 3. But my entire project is in Swift v2.3 and Its very difficult to change everything so I want to keep in Swift v2.3 only.

So I am using Firebase 3x series.

I tried Firebase iOS kit v3.10, v3.12 and v3.16

All works perfectly fine with lower iOS 10x and higher 11.1.1
but not receiveing notification on 11.1

Do I need to do anything from my end or is it firebase issue ?

> To Upgrade to Firebase v4, need to upgrade Swift to v3 or v4
>
> To upgrade to Swift v4, need to upgrade Xcode to v9
>
> To upgrade to Xcode v9, need to upgrade Mac os to 10.12

So, What is the stable version of Firebase 3.x series compatible with
swift 2.3 and iOS 11.1

Comment: You should really make the effort to migrate from Swift 2.3 to Swift 3.2 or even to Swift 4. I recently went through the same process and initially it was a little overwhelming but after working for a couple of hours it went smoothly. You're going to need to do that anyway; as Firebase evolves the older API's will not be (as) supported; FIRDataSnapshot -> DataSnapshot for example.

Comment: @Jay Updated the question and added explanation on difficulty on upgrading

Comment: Other than changing the function calls etc in your code, it should be pretty straight forward. Update to 10.12, install XCode 9, pod update your firebase then update to swift 4.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem last week.

I resolved this by adding "content_available" = true in my push messages.

Take a look at : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref